# HD TV Signal reception at night

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radio, antennas

Why is on air HD TV signal reception better at night?
During the daytime the reception of HD TV broadcasts is markedly lower than at night with the same antenna position. 
Does the sun have components in its radiation that cause this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the solar wind is part of the explanation.

One of the ways radio waves propagate is by bouncing off of the ionosphere.  (See for example this [Wikipedia article on skywave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skywave).)  The layer they bounce off of [changes in height](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennelly%E2%80%93Heaviside_layer) due to the Earth's changing orientation with respect to the solar wind.  It is lower during the day and higher at night which results in longer transmission of radio signals.

Comment: That could be the case possibly for VHF, but very unlikely for UHF. Even for VHF the refraction at night could make a bigger difference

Comment: Actually also tropospheric ducting.